# what is the Time Complextity of a below function?

Tags: c++, c++17, primes

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int n){
     if(n == 1 || n == -1)
          return false
     else if (n ==2 || n == 3)
          return true;
     else if((n+1)%6 == 0 || (n-1)%6 == 0)
          return true;
     return false;
}

int main()
{
    int n{0};
    cin >> n;
    cout << isPrime(n) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

what is the time complexity of isPrime() function and is it correct solution to check whether the number is prime or not ?

Comment: Worry about correctness before checking efficiency. One can make a function extremely efficient by tossing correct behavior (as you have demonstrated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only does a handful of divisibility checks and has no loops or recursion, thus it is simply *O*(1) and is not a correct prime number check.

The third check makes very little sense. Why would a number be prime if it is one away from a multiple of 6? I mean it happens to work for 5 and 7, for 11 and 13, and for 17 and 19, but fails for 25. 25 is one away from 24 but is not prime. It's like calculating π as 22/7 — it's an okay first approximation but it's clearly not the right formula.

Comment: All the prime numbers > 3 are +/-1 from a multiple of 6, so that's a good way to eliminate non-primes.  It is not, however, sufficient to ensure that something is a prime - as you showed for 25.